# How to select arrays with different lengths from a "parental" array?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, range

I am new to Python. I have an array of float64 symmetrically distributed around zero `(e.g. [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]);`

Then, I need to select different arrays symmetrically distributed around zero in that array `(e.g. 1st array_range [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]`, 2nd `array_range [ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`, 3rd `array_range [-1, 0, 1])` to calculate the increasing area under a curve (e.g. `x1= [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]`and `y1= [10, 30, 60, 100, 70, 55, 20]`;  `x2= [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`and `y2= [10, 40, 100, 60, 40, 20]` and so on..

Is there someone how know if there is a specific code in Python to do that?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do a basic Python tutorial? Are you familiar with indexing and slicing? Is your data actually "an array of float64" (i.e. from ``array`` or ``numpy``) or just a list of integers as shown?

Comment: Can't you just use Python's range?  `range(-3, 4)`  (where te "4" stands for 3 + 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing to truncate one more element off the front and back of the original array each iteration.

```
data = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(data)//2):
    sub = data[i:len(data)-i]
    print(sub)
```

output

```
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
[-1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Just use ``[i:-i]``, there is no need to fetch ``len(data)`` each time.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That will work for all but the first iteration (`i == 0`) since `[0:-0]` will return an empty list

Comment: You know that the pattern `len(data)-i]` is reduntant in Python, right? You can just use negative indexes to count from the end - your line would be `sub = data[i:-i]` .

Comment: @jsbueno Read the comment immediately above yours.

Comment: Anyway, this answer is redundant. The OP can just use 'range". It is still an anti pattern to use "len(x) - i" in indexes.

Comment: @CoryKramer Good point. It might be preferable to handle the original list outside of the loop, though.

Comment: Thak you so much for your help! 
I also wrote this working code:
# output_x = [[] for i in range(len(data_x) // len(data_x) -1)]
# for i in range(len(data_x) // 2 - 1):
#         x1= data_x[i+1:-i-1]
#         output_x.append([i, x1])
I did the same for the y-axis. So that I generate as output two lists both including several arrays. Now do you know how I can apply the np.trapz function between each array of that lists to calculate the area? 
(I’m partitioning an asymmetric curve in more and more parts to calculate the corresponding areas)

Comment: @Krystal Stack Overflow is designed for single question + single answer. If you have a follow-up question, please feel free to post a new question and include the relevant code snippet and info to that question.

Comment: @CoryKramer ok, thank you. I am new also here I didn't know that. Sorry